# How to check the convergence of the following series.

Tags: calculus, sequences-and-series, convergence-divergence

I'm having a little though time trying to proof the convergence of this couple of series. Hope you could help me. Thx.

- $\left(\displaystyle \sum_{i=2}^n \dfrac{1}{i(\ln i)^p}\right)$,  for every  $p>0$
- $\left(\displaystyle \sum_{i=1}^n \dfrac{i^{k-1}}{i^k+1}\right)$, for every  $k>2$

(P.S. I think both of them are evaluated as $n\to\infty$)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

*HINT*

use integral convergence test:

$$\int_1^{\infty}\frac{1}{x\log^p{x}} \sim\sum \frac{1}{n \log^p{n}}$$

use comparasion test:

$$\frac{n^{p}}{n^{p+1}+ 1} \ge \frac{1}{2n}$$